# Can someone explain what is wrong with my code and how my teacher's code works?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, evaluation, emu8086

I'm trying to write some code in emu8086. I'm new to assembly so it's still a bit confusing to me. In my assignment, for one of the exercises I have to:

> Make a code that solves: r=(x-y*z)/t
> The values are: x = 2000; y = -500; z = 200; t = 300; r = ?

I checked the solution given in our course:

> ```
> x dw 2000
> y dw -500
> z dw 200
> t dw 300
> r dw ?
> ____________________
> mov ax, y
> imul z
> mov cx, dx
> mov bx, ax
> mov ax, x
> cwd
> sub ax, bx
> sbb dx, cx
> idiv t
> mov r, ax
> ```

and I don't understand why using the instructions `cwd` and `sbb` is needed, and also the lines:

> ```
> mov cx, dx 
> mov bx, ax
> ```

> ```
> sbb dx, cx
> ```

This is the code that I wrote myself:

```
mov AX, y
imul z
    
mov BX, x
sub BX, AX
    
idiv t
mov r, BX
```

and these are the results I get:

```
x = 07D0h
y = 0FE0Ch
z = 00C8h
t = 012Ch
r = 8E70h
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CU9Q.png)

The value for *r* should be `0154h`, which is 340 in decimal.

I guess the problem might be related to the multiplication resulting in a negative number, but I don't understand how to fix it.

Could someone explain the purpose of the fore-mentioned
instructions in this code, how they affect the whole process and why my own code is wrong? Besides that, are there other ways of solving this without having to use those instructions?

Comment: Consult a reference about how `idiv` works. It uses `dx` for the top 16 bits of the divisor so you need to make sure `dx` is correct. The `cwd` instruction does that. Similarly `imul` produces a 32 bit result and `y*z` is `-100000` which does not fit into 16 bits either hence you need to use 32 bit subtraction implemented using `sub` and `sbb` to propagate carry (borrow). Yes, you can simulate the `cwd` and the `sbb` using other instructions, for example using explicit conditional jumps.

Comment: `cwd` stands for "convert word to doubleword", which takes `ax` and sign-extends it into `dx`. That is, if `ax < 7FFFh` it will load 0 into `dx`, otherwise it sets `dx` to `FFFF`. In either case, `ax` is unchanged. `sbb` is "subtract with borrow" and will subtract an extra 1 if the carry flag was set prior to the subtraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing is implementing 32 bit arithmetic using 16 bit registers. This is needed because the intermediate values of your calculation do not fit into 16 bits, and partially also because `idiv` and `imul` operate on 32 bit register pair `dx` and `ax`.

The `imul z` result is `-100000` but that does not fit into 16 bits and is already split into `dx=0xFFFE=-2` and `ax=0x7960=31072` automatically. To do the subtraction `x-y*z` `x` is also extended to 32 bits, using the `cwd` instruction. Before that the `y*z` temporary is moved away to the `cx:bx` pair. The subtraction is done by first doing the low 16 bits using plain `sub` and the top 16 bits using `sbb` to propagate the carry (borrow). The result is left in `dx:ax` which is the implicit input to the `idiv`. The quotient is then produced in `ax`.

Your code is wrong because the `sub BX, AX` leaves the result in `bx` which is not used by the `idiv` at all since that operates on `dx:ax` implicitly. You then store that `bx` which isn't even the output of the `idiv`. You also only calculated using the low 16 bits, so the result is `2000-31072=-29072=0x8E70`.

Yes, you can simulate the `cwd` and the `sbb` using other instructions, for example using explicit conditional jumps. `cwd` just sign extends `ax` into `dx` meaning if `ax` is negative then `dx` will be set to `0xffff` and to zero otherwise. You can simply do this by hand, or fill `dx` with the sign bit using arithmetic shift or if you are permitted to know that `x` is always positive then just zero `dx`. Instead of `sbb` you can just check if there was a carry (borrow) and subtract 1 from the result if so before handling the rest with a plain `sub`.